# Show "0" instead of empty with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run this query the result is empty and it doesn't show me anything

```
select  pr.idpreorden,p.DescProducto,pr.Id_Producto, pr.pre_preciounitario,
        pr.pre_cantidad,pr.pre_total
    from  preorden pr
    inner join  Clientes c  ON c.Id_Clientes = pr.Id_Clientes
    inner join  productos p  ON p.Id_Producto = pr.Id_Producto
    where  pr.estado='A'
      and  c.Id_Clientes = '2'
```

What I want is that instead of not throwing anything or empty, it gives me a "0" result, as could this indicate to my established query.

I want it to show like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` (instead of `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN`) produces a row in the output even if there is no matching row in the 'right' table.  It will produce all `NULL` for the missing data.

Then you can use `COALESCE(p.DescProducto, 0)` to turn `NULL` into `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping it in an "if not exists" statement then if it returns no lines do select 0 as preorden, 0 as descproducto , etc.
Then in the else statement put the actual query to be returned.
I think that should work . Mucha suerte .
Edit: I also didn't realize there was a search argument and in that case the answer of Rick James is better.
My answer I believe is valid when there is no search argument however

Comment: Your answer would be so much more helpful if you included the actual SQL statement that does all the things you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism man . I'll keep that in mind however the original publisher didn't ask for the actual SQL statement and considering SQL is rather easy to convert to from English then there shouldn't be any problem implementing what I suggested. Either way if the OP needs more help I'd prefer he ask for it.Maybe he doesn't want me to write it out for him.